# i can't install Ubuntu on my Microsoft Surface 3 (not Surface Pro)

Tags: surface, df

My Surface 3 has 2gb ram and 18gb free space in 64 gb hard drive. It shows this when installing ubuntu:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How were you trying to install Ubuntu? It seems like a bad bootable USB problem. Was your ISO good?

Comment: I also have problem with ubuntu 16.10 on surface 3. In my case I was just trying to use the live. I was able to go through the selection where I need to choose between install, live, oem install... But when I choose live, I get to this screen with command line. My usb is fine though because I can boot from it on another computer.